# Spring-batch exception: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [] was registered

Tags: spring-batch, jobs, restart

I am seeing this exception when stopping a running job using jobOperator.stop(id) or when I want to restart it using jobOperator.restart(id).
I don't have any idea why the MapJobRegistry is empty ... Am I missing a step ?
I have reproduced the problem using the complete example from https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-batch-processing.git

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

   @Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
// end::setup[]

@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;

// tag::readerwriterprocessor[]
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>()
        .name("personItemReader")
        .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv"))
        .delimited()
        .names(new String[]{"firstName", "lastName"})
        .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {{
            setTargetType(Person.class);
        }})
        .build();
}

@Bean
public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
    return new PersonItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
        .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
        .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)")
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .build();
}
// end::readerwriterprocessor[]

// tag::jobstep[]
@Bean
public Job importUserJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener listener, Step step1) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob")
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .listener(listener)
        .flow(step1)
        .end()
        .build();
}

@Bean
public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
        .<Person, Person> chunk(10)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer)
        .build();
}
// end::jobstep[]

@Bean
public JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher() throws Exception {
    SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
    jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
    jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
    return jobLauncher;
}
}
```

The rest controller

```
@RestController
public class BatchController {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchController.class);

@Autowired
JobLauncher simpleJobLauncher;

@Autowired
Job importUserJob;

@Autowired
JobOperator jobOperator;

@RequestMapping("/startNewJob")
public String handle()  {
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis())
                .toJobParameters();
        JobExecution jobExecution = simpleJobLauncher.run(importUserJob, jobParameters);

        return jobExecution.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        return ("An error has occured, please check the logs");
    }
}

@RequestMapping("/stopJob/{id}")
public Boolean stopJob(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {
    logger.info("stopJob "+id);
    return jobOperator.stop(id);
}

@RequestMapping("/restartJob/{id}")
public Long restartJob(@PathVariable Long id) throws Exception {
    logger.info("restartJob "+id);
    return jobOperator.restart(id);
}
}
```

Stacktrace while restarting the job
2020-11-12 21:47:16.452 ERROR 26252 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [importUserJob] was registered] with root cause

org.springframework.batch.core.launch.NoSuchJobException: No job configuration with the name [importUserJob] was registered
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry.getJob(MapJobRegistry.java:68) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.getJob(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator.restart(SimpleJobOperator.java:275) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$44ee6049.invoke() ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:685) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$853e8727.restart() ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]
at com.example.batchprocessing.BatchController.restartJob(BatchController.java:60) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]

Answer (score 6):

I simply added a JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor and set it the jobRegistry.

```
   @Autowired
   JobRegistry jobRegistry;

   @Bean
   public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor() {
       JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor postProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
       postProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
       return postProcessor;
   }
```

Answer (score 5):

The `JobOperator` requires a `JobLocator` to locate jobs to restart, stop, etc. This `JobLocator` (typically a `MapJobRegistry`) should be populated with known jobs, and this should be done either manually or by adding a [JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/support/JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.html) to the application context.

This is explained in the reference documentation here: [JobRegistry](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/job.html#jobregistry).

Answer (score 0):

You can also trigger job using jobLauncher. Here is a [blog](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-batch/job-scheduler-example/) explaining it.

In short you can refer to this code.

```java
@Component
public class JobScheduler
{
  @Autowired
  JobLauncher jobLauncher;
   
  @Qualifier("jobBeanName") // if you have multiple jobs
  @Autowired
  Job job;
   
  @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
  public void runJob() {
    jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
  }
}
```